# Java If statement that can change String

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

I'm making an app where a user can pick a city in a giving area, and this brings up a listview of events in that given area. I'm using this video guide as a way to help me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjHYyAJQ7Vw&index=21&list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A  . Unlike the person in the video, I need to have my list say one thing, and the results say another. I'm having trouble finding a way to change my String before it gets to the try statement. For example, I want to change "City history" to "beachcity" (so it takes them to this page), "Fort Macon" to "fortmacon", and so on. That away the user sees something they can understand.

Is there a way to do this? At worst, is there a way to change this with some if statement? Below is the JAVA code

```
public class Alantic extends ListActivity{
String classes[] = { "City history", "Fort Macon", "example2", "example3", "example4", "example5", "example6"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Alantic.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String abc = classes[position];
    try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.techreviewsandhelp.carteretcountyhistoryguide." + abc);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent("Alantic.this, ourClass");
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How this code should work is items within String classes shows up in a list (which it does)> user clicks item on list> item goes to String abc> (I need something to convert the item to something else. City history needs to be BEACHCITY, Fort Macon needs to be FORTMACON, and so on)> what's converted will go into the Class ourClass line? this looks for the same "com.tech...." within the manifest action list> this starts another Java file that matches up with the action name> this starts the layout and any functions (buttons and what not) that I want.

I don't think I can use spaces in action names, but giving I can. I would still need the name to change, because I have to do this exact same thing in multiple cities. This means I have to reuse City history, cemeteries, and several other things as a list item for each city.

Below is my code from the manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.techreviewsandhelp.com.carteretcountyhistoryguide"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:screenOrientation='portrait' >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.techreviewsandhelp.com.carteretcountyhistoryguide.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.techreviewsandhelp.carteretcountyhistoryguide.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


     <activity
        android:name=".Alantic"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.techreviewsandhelp.carteretcountyhistoryguide.Alantic" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name=".Beachcity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.techreviewsandhelp.carteretcountyhistoryguide.BEACHCITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity
        android:name=".FortMacon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.techreviewsandhelp.carteretcountyhistoryguide.FORTMACON" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I tested out the actions, and they  work fine.

Comment: May I know , why you mentioned `(Aniruddha)` in title ? Please get rid of personal attacks.

Comment: Reposting won't help you get more answers.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ My other thread was on hold, and Aniruddha was helping me on it. Aniruddha said he couldn't show the answer in the comments, and for me to open a new thread.

Comment: BTW, how do you change the color background and text color in a listview? Almost my entire app has a black background with white text. The list has a white background and black text.

Comment: To change the list view colour, you have to options, you can try to change the style for an list item. Or you can create a custom list adapter. Then you can point the adapter to your custom list item where you can change background and text colour.

Comment: The proper response to a closed question is *not* to open another one. You need to alter your original question to improve it, after which it could be reopened. Cluttering SO with reposts isn't particularly polite.

Comment: It seems like this method won't work. Not to sound like an idiot, but what is this thing in this picture called under the category? http://img.rochdev.com/rochtask/2.png Is there a way to modify what it shows? Like if I have 2 of those things, and one is city while the other is event. Can I have the event one only show the stuff for whichever city is picked? So event A list will only show when city A is picked, or event B list will show only when city B is picked

Comment: I found the name. Spinner is the last thing I thought it would be called. I thought it was a pull down tab.

Answer (score 0):

For instance have two arrays - one with the display names and one with the names to send. Or use a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), but that is probably overkill.

As such:

```
public class Alantic extends ListActivity{
String displayClasses[] = { "City history", "Fort Macon", "example2", "example3", "example4", "example5", "example6"};
String classes[] = { "BEACHCITY", "FORTMACON", "example2", "example3", "example4", "example5", "example6"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Alantic.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, displayClasses));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String abc = classes[position];
    try{
       Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.techreviewsandhelp.carteretcountyhistoryguide." + abc);
       Intent ourIntent = new Intent("Alantic.this, ourClass");
       startActivity(ourIntent);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Another option is to create a custom (Array) Adapter and use a custom data class containing both names.

Comment: It doesn't work. Here is a link to the workbook. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1sg8p9uvjbolqxx/AADcMiPWB_JVEysb01B_hUtBa

Comment: How haven't three people noticed the error `new Intent("Alantic.this, ourClass");`. Which creates intent with action instead of ComponentName.

Comment: @DoctororDrive because that's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Alantic.this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,     displayClasses));

   Hashmap hm = new HashMap<String, String>;
    hm.put("City History","BEACHCITY");// add your items

   }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    HashMap hasmap = new HashMap
    String abc = classes[position ];// this becomes your key
    String newString = hm.get(abc);
    try{
   Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.techreviewsandhelp.carteretcountyhistoryguide." +       newString);
   Intent ourIntent = new Intent("Alantic.this, ourClass");
   startActivity(ourIntent);
   }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
```

Comment: I just copy and paste your code in to see if it would work, and I got a few errors after I imported HashMap. 2 abc cannot be resolved to a variable, Hashmap cannot be resolved to a type, hm cannot be resolved, Syntax error on tokens (link 32).

Comment: I changed the hashmap to a typed map. In terms of the ABC, I have never used your method… you question was around tying the values to each other.  I use a custom list adapter..  then I get my values like this...             String yourStringFromListItem = ((YourModel) getListAdapter().getItem(position)).yourGetter();

Comment: The new code gave me 7 errors. The abc is only the name of the string that gets the name of the class name the user picked from the list.

Comment: Again, I am not sure why you are going about the ABC that way. Create a custom list adapter, a data model for your data, then use similar code to what I posted in previous comment.  It works for me.  Do you know how to create a custom list adapter? The problem is when you don't use a custom adapter is you can't specify the returned info from your list item.  So with a custom list adapter you can return what you want. That would become your abc then you can use that as the key to find your value in the hashmap.